# Most performant calculation of Newtonian forces in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, scipy

For an exercise in university, we had to implement a [Leapfrog integrator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration) with exact Newtonian forces in Python. The course is over and our solutions were all more than good enough, but I wondered if/how one could improve the performance of the force calculation even more.

The bottleneck is to calculate all forces (aka accelerations):

[image: a<sub>i</sub> = Σ<sub>j≠i</sub> Gm<sub>j</sub> / |r<sub>1</sub>-r<sub>2</sub>|<sup>3</sup> * (r<sub>1</sub>-r<sub>2</sub>)]

for a large (1000 and bigger) number of particles N (i,j<N).

Here r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> are the 3-dimensional vectors of the position of the particles stored in an ndarray of shape (N,3) and Gm is the particle mass times the gravitational constant which I saved in an ndarray of shape (N).

The fastest version I found so far is the following:

```
def a(self):
    sep = self.r[np.newaxis, :] - self.r[:, np.newaxis]
    # Calculate the distances between all particles with cdist
    # this is much faster than by hand
    dists = cdist(self.r, self.r)
    scale =dists*dists*dists
    # set diagonal elements of dist to something != 0, to avoid division by 0
    np.fill_diagonal(scale,1)
    Fsum = (sep/scale.reshape(self.particlenr,self.particlenr,1))*self.Gm[:,None]
    return np.add.reduce(Fsum,axis=1)
```

But it bugs me that this is probably not the fastest version. The first line seems to be too slow when comparing to cdist which is doing essentially the same calculation. Also, this solution does not use the symmetry of switching r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> in the problem and calculates all elements twice.

Do you know any performance improvements (without changing the force-calculation to some approximation or changing the programming language)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a try: I implemented a routine, which determines a single `a_i`:

```
import numpy as np

GM = .01  #  article mass times the gravitation

def calc_a_i(rr, i):
    """ Calculate one a_i """
    drr = rr - rr[i, :] # r_j - r_i
    dr3 = np.linalg.norm(drr, axis=1)**3  # |r_j - r_i|**3
    dr3[i] = 1  # case i==j: drr = [0, 0, 0]
    # this would be more robust (elimnate small denominators):
    #dr3 = np.where(np.abs(dr3) > 1e-12, dr3, 1)
    return np.sum(drr.T/dr3, axis=1)

n = 4000 # number of particles
rr = np.random.randn(n, 3) # generate some particles

# Calculate each a_i separately:
aa = np.array([calc_a_i(rr, i) for i in range(n)]) * GM # all a_i
```

To test it, I ran:

```
In [1]: %timeit aa = np.array([calc_a_i(rr, i) for i in range(n)])
1 loops, best of 3: 2.93 s per loop
```

The easiest way to speed up such code, is to use [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) for faster evaluation of array expressions:

```
import numexpr as ne
ne.set_num_threads(1)  # multithreading causes to much overhead

def ne_calc_a_i( i):
    """ Use numexpr - here rr is global for easier parallelization"""
    dr1, dr2, dr3 = (rr - rr[i, :]).T # r_j - r_i
    drrp3 = ne.evaluate("sqrt(dr1**2 + dr2**2 + dr3**2)**3")
    drrp3[i] = 1
    return np.sum(np.vstack([dr1, dr2, dr3])/drrp3, axis=1)

# Calculate each a_i separately:
aa_ne = np.array([ne_calc_a_i(i) for i in range(n)]) * GM  # all a_i
```

This improves the speed by a factor of 2:

```
    In [2]: %timeit aa_ne = np.array([ne_calc_a_i(i) for i in range(n)])
    1 loops, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop
```

To speed up the code further, let's run it on a [IPython Cluster](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_multiengine.html#ipython-s-direct-interface):

```
# Start local cluster with 4 clients in a shell with: 
# ipcluster start -n 4

rc = Client()  # clients of cluster
dview = rc[:]  # view of clusters

dview.execute("import numpy as np")  # import libraries on clients
dview.execute("import numexpr as ne")
dview.execute("ne.set_num_threads(1)")

def para_calc_a(dview, rr):
    """ Only in function for %timeit """
    # send rr and ne_calc_a_i() to clients:
    dview.push(dict(rr=rr, ne_calc_a_i=ne_calc_a_i), block=True)
    return np.array(dview.map_sync(ne_calc_a_i, range(n)))*GM
```

The speedup is more than a factor of four:

```
In[3] %timeit aa_p = para_calc_a(dview, rr)
1 loops, best of 3: 612 ms per loop
```

As @mathdan already noted, it is not obvious how to optimize such a problem: It depends on your CPU architecture if the memory bus or the floating point unit is the limiting factor, which calls for different techniques.

For further gains you might want to look at [Theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/): It can dynamically generate code GPU code from Python.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a bit more optimal:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform    

def a6(r, Gm):
    dists = pdist(r)
    dists *= dists*dists
    dists = squareform(dists)
    np.fill_diagonal(dists, 1.)
    sep = r[np.newaxis, :] - r[:, np.newaxis]
    return np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik', sep, Gm/dists)
```

Speed gain is mainly due to the `einsum` line; Using `pdist` and `squareform` like this is only marginally faster than the original way with `cdist`.

You can take it a bit further still, e.g. by using threading and Numba (version 0.17.0 required). Although the code below is very ugly and surely can be improved a lot, it is pretty fast.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numba import jit
from threading import Thread
NUM_THREADS = 2  # choose wisely

def a_numba_par(r, Gm):
    a = np.zeros_like(r)
    N = r.shape[0]

    offset = range(0, N+1, N//NUM_THREADS)
    chunks = zip(offset, offset[1:])
    threads = [Thread(target=_numba_loop, args=(r,Gm,a)+c) for c in chunks]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    return a

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def _numba_loop(r, Gm, a, i1, i2):
    N = r.shape[0]
    for i in range(i1, i2):
        _helper(r, Gm, i, 0  , i, a[i,:])
        _helper(r, Gm, i, i+1, N, a[i,:])
    return a

@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def _helper(r, Gm, i, j1, j2, a):
    for j in range(j1, j2):
        dx = r[j,0] - r[i,0]
        dy = r[j,1] - r[i,1]
        dz = r[j,2] - r[i,2]

        sqeuc = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz
        scale = Gm[j] / (sqeuc * math.sqrt(sqeuc))

        a[0] += scale * dx
        a[1] += scale * dy
        a[2] += scale * dz
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that numpy is actually double-computing the distances (since it will always be symmetric). It is probably doing one calculation and assigning the same value in two places.

A few of ideas do occur to me, though:

1. You could follow the numpy source and write a customized version of cdist. It may be that the program is parsing many options *each time* you iterate. Not much, but perhaps it could give you a small percentage bump.
2. Pre-allocate. Each time you run a(), you are potentially reallocating the memory for all the intermediate matrix values. Could you make these persistent quantities?

I haven't run through the calculations yet, but I would not be surprised if you could elegantly reduce the redundant symmetric calculations somehow.